# How Do I Use Spacebars Template Helpers to Prevent Need For Unnecessary Templates?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
{{> eventTitle}}

<template name="eventTitle">
    {{eventTitle}}
</template>
```

Is there a way to cut out the template and just do:

```
{{eventTitle}}
```

Then in the js file:

```
Template.eventTitle.eventTitle = function () {
    return "Title!";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Handlebars.registerHelper just like this :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("eventTitle",function(){
    return "Title!";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Meteor 1.0 use [Template.registerHelper(name,function)](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper) to register a global template helper.